Definition of free fall in GR
I apologize if this question is very elementary. Somewhere I've found the following:
Freely falling observers (resp. photon) move on timelike (resp. null) geodesics.
Please note that by definition, any curve $\gamma$ in any spacetime $M$ is a geodesic if
$$\nabla_{ \dot{\gamma}} \dot{\gamma}=0$$ where $\dot{\gamma}$ represent the tangent vector of the curve $\gamma.$ In local coordinates, this is equivant to
$$\frac{d^2x^\mu}{ds^2}+{\Gamma^\mu}_{\nu\lambda}\frac{dx^\nu}{ds}\frac{dx^\lambda}{ds}=0$$ for all indices $\mu.$
However, by Free fall, I understand (classically)
$$\frac{d^2x^\mu}{ds^2}=0.$$ Clearly, these two definitions are not equivalent unless all the $\Gamma$'s are identically zero. Now the question is:
Do people say "Freely falling observers (resp. photon) move on timelike (resp. null) geodesics" a bit informally, or do they mean it literally/precisely? I would be very happy if someone could explain this without too many physics jargons.

Where does your "classical" definition come from?


Do people say "Freely falling observers (resp. photon) move on timelike (resp. null) geodesics" a bit informally, or do they mean it literally/precisely? I would be very happy if someone could explain this without too many physics jargons.

Literally and precisely. The condition you wrote down is the zero acceleration condition in a curved spacetime. To make this obvious, start from your definition of free fall in Cartesian coordinates. Then work out what do they imply in a different coordinate system, such as spherical coordinates. You will notice the Christoffel symbols appear naturally.
In summary, your definition is coordinate-dependent. The geodesic definition is a coordinate-independent (and thus objective) way of stating the zero-acceleration condition.
